# Samsung Galaxy S20 broke dark mode sometimes

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy, android-darkmode

I have application, which set mode dark mode in Application:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(isDarkModeOn() ? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES : AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

It works everywhere as expected, but only on Samsung S20 / Android 11 it sometimes mix light/dark theme for main activity.

I found article which could explain it, but I am not sure who (Google or Samsung) fixed problem and how.

[Google app dark mode is busted on many non-Pixel phones right now](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/05/13/google-app-dark-mode-is-busted-on-many-non-pixel-phones-right-now/)

Comment: Are you seeing this with actual production apps? I have had this a lot in debug versions but it could never be recreated after the app was deployed properly!

Comment: @HenryTwist I tested release build, but problem was same.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve this problem.

Main issue was that drawables colors has been defines  over @color/somecolor, where this color was defined in:

```
drawable\somedrawable.xml
values\colors.xml
values-night\colors.xml
```

I had to replace this with two drawables (each point to own color inside colors.xml):

```
values\colors.xml
drawable\somedrawable.xml
drawable-night\somedrawable.xml
```

Stil do not know why this problem appear only on Samsung S20 with Android 11.